# Flurry Push Not Opening Deep Linking

Tags: android, firebase, flurry

I'm Trying To Send Deep Linking Notification Using Flurry, Instead The Notification Opens The App & Plays No Sound Either, I'm Using AutoIntegration For This, And I Have MyFlurryMessagingListener Class As It Is From Flurry Documentation. I have No Errors, Just This Problem, And Yes I made Sure To Choose "Deep Linking" When Creating A Push In Flurry Dashboard.

Build Gradle

```
 implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:marketing:11.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

MyApplication Class

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "REGISTERED TOKEN: " + refreshedToken);

        FlurryMarketingOptions flurryMessagingOptions = new FlurryMarketingOptions.Builder()
                .setupMessagingWithAutoIntegration()
                .withDefaultNotificationIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .withDefaultNotificationIconAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                .build();

        FlurryMarketingModule marketingModule = new FlurryMarketingModule(flurryMessagingOptions);

        new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                .withLogEnabled(true)
                .withModule(marketingModule)
                .build(this, "CCCCCTESTTESTTESTTEST");
    }

}
```

MyFlurryMessagingListener  Class

```java
public class MyFlurryMessagingListener implements FlurryMessagingListener {

    final static String LOG_TAG = MyFlurryMessagingListener.class.getCanonicalName();

    Context context;

    public MyFlurryMessagingListener(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onNotificationReceived(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {

        // determine if you'd like to handle the received notification yourself or not

        boolean handled = false;

        // flurry will not show notification if app is in foreground, so handle it appropriately

        if (FlurryMessaging.isAppInForeground()) {

            // handle the notification using data from FlurryMessage

            // NOTE: since you are handling the notification, be sure to call logNotificationOpened and logNotificationCancelled after this

            handled = true;

        }

        return handled;

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onNotificationClicked(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {

        // NOTE: THIS WILL ONLY BE CALLED IF FLURRY HANDLED onNotificationReceived callback

        // determine if you'd like to handle the clicked notification yourself or not

        boolean handled = false;



        return handled;

    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationCancelled(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Notification cancelled!");

    }

    @Override

    public void onTokenRefresh(String refreshedToken) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Token refreshed - " + refreshedToken);

    }

    @Override

    public void onNonFlurryNotificationReceived(Object nonFlurryMessage) {

        // If Flurry receives a non-Flurry message, it will be passed to you here. You can cast the object

        // based on the push provider. For example...

        if (nonFlurryMessage instanceof RemoteMessage) {

            RemoteMessage firebaseMessage = (RemoteMessage) nonFlurryMessage;



        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a deeplink, you need to perform additional integration steps, even with Auto-Integration.

1. Setup your app to use deeplinking:

> ```
> <activity     
>    android:name=".DeeplinkTestActivity">
>
>    <intent-filter>
>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>
>       <!-- This will open deeplinks structured like - "testapp://deeplink/example" -->
>
>       <data
>
>          android:scheme="testapp"
>          android:host="deeplink"
>          android:pathPrefix="/example" />
>
>    </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> ```

2. In the app's onNotificationClicked method, retrieve your deeplink, included in the push with the "deeplink" keyword

@Override

```
public boolean onNotificationClicked(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {

    // NOTE: THIS METHOD WILL ONLY BE CALLED IF FLURRY HANDLED onNotificationReceived callback

    // determine if you'd like to handle the clicked notification yourself or not

    boolean handled = false;

    // see if notification contains deeplink

    if (flurryMessage.getAppData() != null && flurryMessage.getAppData().containsKey("deeplink")) {

        String deeplink = flurryMessage.getAppData().get("deeplink");

        // create the Intent

        final Intent deeplinkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        deeplinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        deeplinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // set the data using your deeplink

        deeplinkIntent.setData(Uri.parse(deeplink));

        // add the FlurryMessage to extras

        FlurryMessaging.addFlurryMessageToIntentExtras(deeplinkIntent, flurryMessage);

        // make sure the deeplink resolves to an activity, then open it

        if (deeplinkIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {

            context.startActivity(deeplinkIntent);

            // tell flurry you've handled the notification

            handled = true;

        }

    }

    return handled;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it would be great if flurry can send notifications to open URL's links, developers could use to promote other apps, I wonder why such feature is absent from flurry push.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your flurry messaging listener on notification clicked method and get the intent to your activity where you want to load the url or where you want to go on click it will work fine.

```
public boolean onNotificationClicked(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {

    // NOTE: THIS WILL ONLY BE CALLED IF FLURRY HANDLED onNotificationReceived callback

    // determine if you'd like to handle the clicked notification yourself or not

    boolean handled = false;
    if (flurryMessage.getAppData() != null && flurryMessage.getAppData().containsKey("deeplink")) {

        String deeplink = flurryMessage.getAppData().get("deeplink");

        // create the Intent
        Log.e("App data",""+flurryMessage.getAppData());

        final Intent deeplinkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //   deeplinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        //   deeplinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // set the data using your deeplink

        deeplinkIntent.setData(Uri.parse(deeplink));

        // add the FlurryMessage to extras
        Log.e("deeplinkurl", "" + Uri.parse(deeplink));
        FlurryMessaging.addFlurryMessageToIntentExtras(deeplinkIntent, flurryMessage);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // make sure the deeplink resolves to an activity, then open it
         if (intent.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager())!=null){

             intent.putExtra("deeplink", deeplink);
             getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

             // tell flurry you've handled the notification

             handled = true;
         }
    }
    return handled;
}
```